# I want to list all files(with absolute path) from a given directory(given absolute path) in the order of the date modified

Tags: shell-script

I want to list all files (**with absolute path**) and only files (not sub-directories) from a given directory in the order of the date modified. I know ls /path_to_dir -t lists files according to the date modified but it does not give the full path
More clarification: My work directory is /home/emirates/Code.
From work directory, I want to list :

- **only files with full abs path**
- **in the order of the file modified**
- **from the directory /var/reports**
- **Note that my work directory could change i.e in prod environment it could be anywhere**

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- ${PWD%/}/path_to_dir/*(NDom.) # regular files only

print -rC1 -- ${PWD%/}/path_to_dir/*(NDom^/) # any type of file except
                                             # directory (so includes
                                             # symlinks, fifos, devices,
                                             # sockets... in addition to
                                             # the regular files above)

print -rC1 -- ${PWD%/}/path_to_dir/*(NDom-^/) # any type except directory 
                                              # but this time the type is
                                              # determined after symlink
                                              # resolution so would also
                                              # exclude symlinks to
                                              # directories.

print -rC1 -- ${PWD%/}/path_to_dir/*(ND-om^/) # same but also use the
                                              # modification time of the target
                                              # of symlinks when sorting

print -rC1 -- path_to_dir/*(ND-om^/:P) # same but print the real path for each
                                       # file. That is, make sure it's absolute
                                       # and none of the path components
                                       # are symlinks.
```

`${PWD%/}` is to handle the case where `$PWD` is `/` so we get `/path_to_dir/files` instead of `//path_to_dir/files`.

That `${PWD%/}/` is only to be prepended to *relative* paths (such as `path_to_dir`) to make them absolute, not for paths that are already absolute (such as `/absolute/path_to_dir`).

So for your `/var/reports`, use `print -rC1 -- /var/reports/*(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find`:

> Note that it assumes the GNU implementation of `find` (and `cut` and `sort`
> which otherwise can't be used portably to process non-text) and that
> file paths don't contain newline characters. Also note that it
> excludes directories but also all the other non-regular types of files
> including symlinks (whether they point to regular files or not),
> fifos, devices, sockets

```
find "$PWD/relative_path" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@\0%p\n"| sort -rn | cut -d '' -f2
```

Will list files of the given path, `maxdepth` tells the level of recursiveness.

---

Borrowed from [Unix/Linux find and sort by date modified](https://superuser.com/a/546900/1001901).

Comment: Note that it assumes the GNU implementation of `find` (and `cut` and `sort` which otherwise can't be used portably to process non-text)  and that file paths don't contain newline characters. Also note that it excludes directories but also all the other non-regular types of files including symlinks (whether they point to regular files or not), fifos, devices, sockets...

Comment: You can't sort `%T+` with `sort -n`. You should use `%T@` instead here.

Comment: Edited again for clarification

Comment: this even works with \t no need for \0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming paths with no newline characters:

```
ls -ltd "$PWD/relative_path/"* | grep -v '^d'
```

If you want to list files in the current directory, just drop `/relative_path`. Obviously, you can also give the absolute path right away:

```
ls -ltd "/var/reports/"* | grep -v '^d'
```

And to list dotfiles too, in Bash and Ksh you can simply substitute the `*` by `{*,.*}`. In Zsh you would need to `setopt cshnullglob` first or the command would fail if either dotfiles or non-dotfiles didn't exist in the directory.

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580868.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the GNU specific parts here could be the `grep -v '^d'` which per POSIX gives unspecified result on non-text (and file names are not guaranteed to be made of text). `{*,.*}` is a csh-ism but wouldn't work as well in shells other than csh (or `zsh -o cshnullglob`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hmm, `{*,.*}` works in Bash, Ksh, Zsh too.

Comment: but differently. For instance, in `zsh`, unless you set the `cshnullglob` option, it will fail the command if there's either no hidden file or no non-hidden file. Many shells will include `.` and `..` which you don't want. Actually, the shell where it works best is `fish` here (or `zsh -o cshnullglob`) rather than `csh` (which includes `.` and `..`). You can shorten it to `{,.}*`. In `zsh`, you'd use `*(D)`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for you perseverance on explaining a lot of things, much appreciated. I think an error message if the directory is empty is acceptable, otherwise I have added your suggestion for Zsh.

Comment: (in bash, you'd also need to disable failglob if enabled (bash has no equivalent to cshnullglob and its failglob takes precedence over nullglob, so like in all Bourn-like or rc-like shells, non-matching globs would be passed unexpanded to `ls` causing error)).